# Yii Radio Buttons

Tags: php, yii

I am using radio buttons in Yii and no matter what I do I can't get the value of the selected button to post. I am sure its just something simple. I am NOT using radioButtonList because I want each button to exist in its own div with an image above it.

Here is my code from the view...

```
<?php $this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name; ?>

<h1>Welcome to <i><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></i></h1>

<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'lead_form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>
<h3>Choose Your Prize!</h3>

 <div id="prizes">
<div class="prize">
<h3>Paypal</h3>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>1)); ?>
</div>
<div class="prize">
<h3>Check</h3>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>2)); ?>
</div>
<div class="prize">
<h3>AlertPay</h3>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>3)); ?>
</div>
<div class="prize">
<h3>Iphone 4</h3>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>4)); ?>
</div>
<div class="prize">
<h3>Ipad 2</h3>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>5)); ?>
</div>
<div class="prize">
<h3>Custom</h3>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>6)); ?>
</div>
</div>
<h3>Enter Your Email</h3>
<div id="mainemail">
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'user_emhttp://stackoverflow.com/editing-    helpail'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'user_email'); ?>
</div>

<div>
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>
```

endWidget(); ?>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>1,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>2,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>3,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>4,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?>
<?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'user_prize',array('value'=>5,'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?>
```

just add

> 'uncheckValue'=>null

in htmlOption array

it will work..

Comment: Man you just saved my day. I was stuck for a whole *day* thanks to this unintuitive feature.

Comment: mind that it will also generate multiple inputs with same id HTML tag which will break some HTML logic

Comment: WTF. I had this same problem...rly yii? seriously, what is even going on here? anyways, thanks 22francis, you are a lifesaver!

Comment: [CHtml#activeRadioButton-detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeRadioButton-detail)

A special option named 'uncheckValue' is available that can be used to specify the value returned when the radio button is not checked. By default, this value is '0'. Internally, a hidden field is rendered so that when the radio button is not checked, we can still obtain the posted uncheck value. If 'uncheckValue' is set as NULL, the hidden field will not be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

In CHtml::activeRadioButtonList's third parameter (htmlOptions) there is an option called 'template'. You should take a look.