# Radio Button group separately in yii2 without using radiolist

Tags: html, yii2, radio-button

I need Radio Button group in separate place in yii2 like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216240/radio-button-group-in-separate-place-in-yii2) . I can customise the radio button like in this picture

[image]

but when I submit the form only the value of last radio is always submitted if last radio button is clicked respective value else null . I am not able to submit previous checked value.
mine form looks like

```html
<div class="cart-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'product_id')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'size_id')->dropDownList(
              ArrayHelper::map(Productsize::find()->where(['product_id'=>$id])->all (), 'product_size_id', 'product_size' ), 
             [ 'prompt'=>'Select size',
               'onchange'=>'
                       $.get( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('cart/lists?id=').'"+$(this).val(), 
               function( data ) {
                          $( "#pricetag11" ).val(data);
               $( "#pricetaghtml" ).html(data);
            });
                   ']); ?> 
 <?php $colors = Productcolor::find()->where(['product_id'=>$id])->all();     ?> 
 <h4>Price:</h4> <p id="pricetaghtml" style="color:red;"></p>
 Select size to see the price
 <?php echo $form->field($model, 'price_id')->hiddenInput(['id'=>'pricetag11'])->label(false)?>
 
 <!-- here is my problem -->
 <h4>Color:</h4>
 <?php foreach($colors as $color):?>
 <div style="background-color:<?= $color->product_color;?>;width:20px;height:20px;padding-left:3px; display: inline-block">  <?= $form->field($model, 'color_id')->radio(['value' =>$color->product_color, 'label'=>'','uncheck'=>'null']); ?></div>
 <?php endforeach;?>
 <!--  -->

   <?= $form->field($model, 'quantity')->textInput(['type' => 'number','min'=>'0','max'=>'9999' , 'placeholder'=>'0']) ?>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

In my scenario, I have to load color (hexcode) from database table and display in form and need to save the respective code in another table using radio button. 
I have tried so many ways to accomplish this task  in yii2 but i am not able. i hope someone will point me to the right direction.

Comment: Use `radioList()` instead.

Comment: Like in this attached picture, I need to customise the button color depending on the color value store in database. I have not found any way of doing in radioList (but i have looked on radiotemplate). If there is any way or documentation to do like this , I am glad to look at this. Thank you for your response.

Comment: In yii, it was solved simply like in normal html form .Is there any way like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053983/yii-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will work,

```
<?=  $form->field($model, 'color_id')->radioList(
        $colors,
        [
            'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
                $return = '<div style="background-color:'.$value.';width:20px;height:20px;padding-left:3px; display: inline-block">';
                $return .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '">';
                $return .= '</div>';
                return $return;
            }
        ]
    )
->label(false); ?>
```

Comment: you just save me ..but i need slight modification on $colors variable to change it to array  which is done by using arrayhelper.  Change this line:   $colors = Productcolor::find()->where(['product_id'=>$id])->all(); 
to this: $colors=ArrayHelper::map(Productcolor::find()->where(['product_id'=>$id])->all(), 'product_color', 'product_color' );

Comment: Is there any way, achieving this result using radio. How can we solve problem when  we need  group of button in different place (one at the top of page, one at middle ,one at bottom). [like this solved in yii1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053983/yii-radio-buttons)

Comment: @Niras. Find a way out , will update the answer if found solution.

Comment: thank you ! For now i have skipped from this mesh using radiolist like you said.